# Template specific constructor

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm writing my own vector class and i got a problem.
i defined my class as template,i have definition for each of the vector sizes and i want specific constructor for each of the vector sizes.
here is the code:

```
    template<int size>
ref class Vector
{
internal:

    Vector(int _x, int _y, int _z, int _w);
private:

    float *m_data = new float[4];
};
```

and the definitions is :

```
using Vector2 = Vector<2>;
using Vector3 = Vector<3>;
using Vector4 = Vector<4>;
```

first of all can i do that? if the answer is yes how?

Comment: Your class `Vector<2>` is completely unrelated to `Vector<3>`, they are different types. For each of the template instantiation, a constructor is being defined, so you are OK. Probably you want to do something else, since I don't see you using the `size` anywhere. If so, clarify the question.

Comment: thanks for response i get my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want common interface, define constructor as having 4 arguments and specialize it. Inside, initialize only those members, that are valid for vector of this size:

```
template <>
Vector<1>::Vector(int _x, int _y, int _z, int _w)
: x(_x) //1D vector has only 'x'
{
}

template <>
Vector<2>::Vector(int _x, int _y, int _z, int _w)
: x(_x)
, y(_y) //2D vector has 'x' and 'y'
{
}
```

Etc. But that's ugly, forces you you to make some things "common", for example you will hold `4` components even for `2D vector`. There are workarounds (templated structure used as member variable, specialized for vector of each size), but that's quite more complicated. Since vectors of different size are in fact **different types**, I would go for full class specialization:

```
template<int size>
class Vector;

template<>
class Vector<1>
{
protected:
    int x;

public:
    Vector(int _x)
    : x(_x)
    { }

    //other members
};

template<>
class Vector<2>
{
protected:
    int x, y;

public:
    Vector(int _x, int _y)
    : x(_x)
    , y(_y)
    { }

    //other members
};
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
Vector<1> v_1(2);
Vector<2> v_2(4, 6);
//etc...
```

Also, second solution will allow clients of your vector to instantiate it only for those `size`s, that you explicitly allow.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want different behaviour for each template instance, you can do it like so:

```
//specific version for when 0 is passed as the template argument
template<>
Vector<0>::Vector (int _x, int _y, int _z, int _w)
{
    //some Vector<0> related stuff
}

//Vector<1> will use the default version

//specific version for when 2 is passed as the template argument
template<>
Vector<2>::Vector (int _x, int _y, int _z, int _w)
{
    //some Vector<2> related stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With C++11, you may do something like:

```
template<int size>
class Vector
{
public:

    template <typename ...Ts,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<size == sizeof...(Ts)>::type>
    explicit Vector(Ts... args) : m_data{static_cast<float>(args)...} {}
private:
    float m_data[size];
};

using Vector2 = Vector<2>;
using Vector3 = Vector<3>;
using Vector4 = Vector<4>;

int main()
{
    Vector2 v2(42, 5);
    Vector3 v3(42, 5, 3);
    Vector4 v4(42, 5, 51, 69);
}
```